# Generated JSON Web Signature in Java produce invalid signature

Tags: java, jwt

Based on [nimbus-jose-jwt](http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwt-with-hmac) Java library, I tried to create the following JSON Web Token (JWT) and signed it using a JSON Web Signature (JWS) using a string "secret" hashed to SHA256.

But after generating serialized string and test it at [jwt.io](http://jwt.io/), i always get the error "Invalid Signature".

When I try to decode at server side using Python decoder, I also get signature error. What could be wrong?

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[32];
String message = "secret";
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
bytes = md.digest(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

JWSSigner signer = new MACSigner(bytes);

// Prepare JWT with claims set
JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet();
claimsSet.setSubject("alice");

SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.HS256), claimsSet);

// Apply the HMAC
signedJWT.sign(signer);

// To serialize to compact form, produces something like
String s = signedJWT.serialize();
```

Comment: What are you using as the secret when verifying the JWT?

Comment: @frasertweedale I'm using a 3rd party python library "pyjwt" and the code is : payload = jwt.decode(request.body,'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])

Comment: OK, well it seems to me that you are using the SHA-256 digest of "secret" as the key to create the MAC, and plain old "secret" for validating.  Does it work with `JWSSigner signer = new MACSigner("secret")` ?

Comment: @frasertweedale I've replace my library from Java side and the primary issue is what you describe, plain old "secret" vs SHA-256 digest of "secret". Problem solved. Thank you

Comment: Great!  I have formulated my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the SHA-256 digest of "secret" as the key to create the MAC, and plain old "secret" for validating.  Replace:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[32];
String message = "secret";
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
bytes = md.digest(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

JWSSigner signer = new MACSigner(bytes);
```

with:

```
JWSSigner signer = new MACSigner("secret");
```